# Hibernate many-to-many lazy initialization exception

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many, lazy-initialization

I'm new in JEE and recently started learning Spring and Hibernate. I'm trying to develop RESTful service for tracking items with categories. I have many-to-many association (one item can have many categories and one category can have many items), three tables: item, category and join table item_category.

I'm using MySQL server, Spring Boot 1.3.1 and Hibernate 4.3

What I want to do right now is to get list of items with categories and categories with list of items. I wrote entire app with API for that and ended up with LazyInitializationException. I tried many approaches but it didn't help. (I can set fetch type EAGER but this is not a solution).

for example, this is API to list all items: `GET /api/item`

and this is output: (not expected!):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily >initialize a collection of role: com.sk.itemlist.domain.Item.categories, could not initialize proxy - no Session
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:101) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]

Same error if you try to get all categories `GET /api/category`, or category by id `GET /api/category/1`

So here's my questions:

1. How to get rid of LazyInitializationException? How can I configure hibernate to re-open session? Or should I initialize collection in DAO layer?
2. I read about DTO pattern, I don't fully understand what it is, should I dig deeper here?
3. I noticed issue when I try to insert data into items. It inserts only into item table, join table and category are empty. I manually added data into DB for testing
4. What is your feeling about entire app? What can I improve here or what should I avoid (if any)

And finally, I uploaded full project here: https://gitlab.com/sksh/ItemList.git
In resources you can find database dump with some random data. Update application.properties with valid db credentials.

Comment: is `public Category findByKey(String key)` in `CategoryDaoImpl.java` the method that you're trying to call which is giving you this exception?

Comment: @Rdx it throws it everywhere, findById, listAll and so on. It started to throw since I added item list in Category.

Comment: GET /api/category throws org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sk.itemlist.domain.Category.items, could not initialize proxy - no Session and vice versa if I try to fetch all items (GET /api/item), but in this case it can't initialize categories

Answer (score 1):

What happens is:

- You ask hibernate to fetch some items
- Hibernate brings them, but does not bring information of item's categories.
- When you try to access these categories after the DB session work is done (in CollectionSerializer), you get that exception
- You need to ask hibernate to, along with the items, to bring the categories along so youll be able to use then (iterate, list, or else) after the session is over.

You should use something like in DAO level..

```
// fetch a Criteria reference and use join fetching
 Criteria c = currentSession().createCriteria(Item.class);
 c.setFetchMode("categories", FetchMode.JOIN);
 c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
 Item result = (Item)c.uniqueResult();
 return result;
```

There are other ways, like declaring in Item

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
```

but it could lead to performance issues

Comment: I changed method findById in ItemDaoImpl using your suggestion, and now getting new exception:

`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sk.itemlist.domain.Category.items, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.sk.itemlist.domain.Item["categories"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.sk.itemlist.domain.Category["itemList"]);`

Comment: Now you have the same problem at the Category perspective.
Your serializer would attempt to write a list of items. Each item has a list of categories. Each categories has a list of items. And so on.. 
You need to decide  where to cut off the references fetching in your representation. And jackson would not do that automatically, you must do some implementation.
What I usually do: I implement myself the information to be returned in the API by using another set of DTOs that are actually serialized by jackson, so I have control of when the collection field should be accessed outside of a session

Comment: So should I use dto objects with all needed info instead of entity objects?

Comment: That's my recommendation. Otherwise tell jackson (dunno how) to when to read the items list of a Category .